# inifinite UIScrollView with preloading

Tags: memory-leaks, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

Im using a very large UIScrollView with webviews/subviews etc, so I need it to be dynamic, and preloaded with 3 container views. It works in the simulator, but crashes on the device with low memory. 
I am adding and removing from the 3 master views using a recursive method

```
private void destroyChildren(UIView view, int level) {
        if (view.Subviews.Length > 0) {
            foreach (UIView subview in view.Subviews) {
                destroyChildren(subview, level++);          // recurse
                subview.RemoveFromSuperview();
                if (subview is UIWebView) {
                    (subview as UIWebView).ShouldStartLoad -= webHandler;   
                }
                if (subview is scrollViewer) {
                    (subview as scrollViewer).clicked -= viewClicked;   
                }

                subview.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan;  // release bgImage?
                subview.Dispose();
            }
        }
        else {
            if (level> 0) {         // dont dispose root view
                  view.Dispose(); 
            }
        }
```

and called with destroyChildren(myView, 0);
The App still crashes after 10 or so page turns with memory warnings. Is this code okay, or even necessary? Should I use some kind of viewcontroller instead.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

From what I know and I hope I am correct about this when you call subview.Dispose() it is not garbage collected immediately but later after some other app usage. Try to set subviews content to null where possible and than call Dispose(). Also consider implementing DidReceiveMemoryWarning method inside your subviews/master views. I am using a similar app using up to three scrollviews each with four pages and it works with no problems.

Comment: FOREACH does not allow setting children to NULL, maybe another function. I impement DidReceiveMemoryWarning, but since everything is Disposed already, its just time to get in the lifeboat.

Comment: FOREACH does not allow setting children to NULL: you have to go through the childs and Call RemoveFromSuperview.